# Need macro to transfer Word data into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I am very new to VBA and need help ! I have VB macro in Excel that grabs the data from a Word document and imports it into Excel worksheet. Currently, the code in macro has expression that clears the active worksheet and places the new records. However, I need only to update active sheet with new records, or add new records. So, trying to figure out how to accomplish it within the existing code.

Here is the macro:

```
Sub getWordFormData()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim CCtl As Word.ContentControl
Dim myFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim myWkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, j As Long

myFolder = "C:\Users\zsirotilo\Documents\Retention DB\Interviews"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If myFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Set myWkSht = ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear

Range("A1") = "Company Name"
Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
Range("C1") = "Date of Interview"
Range("C1").Font.Bold = True
Range("D1") = "Type of Company by Number(see Case Notes)"
Range("D1").Font.Bold = True

i = myWkSht.Cells(myWkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
strFile = Dir(myFolder & "\*.docx", vbNormal)

While strFile <> ""
i = i + 1

Set myDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=myFolder & "\" & strFile,
AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

With myDoc
j = 0
For Each CCtl In .ContentControls
j = j + 1
myWkSht.Cells(i, j) = CCtl.Range.Text
Next
myWkSht.Columns.ColumnWidth = 25
End With
myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set myDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set myWkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the Word document store all of these records or do you recieve a Word document that only has new records?

Comment: I receive Word docs with only new records ans save into specific folder. So there will be new docs coming all the time that need to be transfered into one master excel worksheet.

Comment: I think just by removing Activesheet.Cells.Clear you should be able to achieve what you're looking for. I'm on mobile so cannot provide a entire answer at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and it works. However, the issue is that I inhereted master excel sheet with data and 1) with ActiveSheet.Clear in macro it overrides all previous records with new ones AND 2) without ActiveSheet.Clear - it creates duplicates of previous records everytime the macro is ran, since it looks for Word docs in the specified folder.

Comment: So move 'processed' word documents to another folder, unless you want to store the files processed in a worksheet and have it run through each one and check document names. That seems like a crazy amount of work for a simple folder switching solution.

Comment: Yes, your thought is logical. However, I am creating a process for data entry resource, so wanted to prevent them accidentally forgetting to move the processed word form to another folder, thus creating dupes at some point.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this process a thought. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should work by removing the line `ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear`, because this is the line that removes the content of the cells.

The line `i = myWkSht.Cells(myWkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is used to know the last row with content to write the new content from then. So it will work as long as the last row has content on the first column.

To avoid to read the same files over and over, it's needed to move the already exported files to another folder. My idea is this:

1. Create a folder, for example:`C:\Users\zsirotilo\Documents\Retention DB\Exported`.
2. Add the line `exportedFolder = "C:\Users\zsirotilo\Documents\Retention DB\Exported"` after the line that defines the variable `myFolder`.
3. After the line `myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False` add the following lines:

   ```
       FileCopy myDoc, exportedFolder & "\" & strFile 'copy word file to Exported folder
       Kill myDoc 'deletes the word file
   ```

Make a backup of the Word files on  `C:\Users\zsirotilo\Documents\Retention DB\Interviews` before testing because it will **delete** the files.

Comment: The issue is that I inhereted master excel sheet with data and 1) with ActiveSheet.Clear in macro it overrides all previous records with new ones AND 2) without ActiveSheet.Clear - it creates duplicates of previous records everytime the macro is ran, since it looks for Word docs in the specified folder.

Comment: @YoniH I modified my answer to avoid the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, I get debugger when I add as follows:                               `myFolder = "C:\Users\zsirotilo\Documents\Retention DB\Interviews"
ExportedFolder = "C:\Users\zsirotilo\Documents\Retention DB\Interviews - Exported"`                                                                                             and then                                                                                                         `myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
FileCopy myDoc, ExportedFolder & "\" & strFile
Kill myDoc`

Comment: @YoniH  Do you mean an error? If the Word files are read only `kill`will fail

Comment: Sorry, I meant debugger error. The word docs are protected (they are generated from the restricted word form template). Debugger error picks up this expression `FileCopy myDoc, ExportedFolder & "\" & strFile`

Comment: Add this before the `FileCopy` line: `SetAttr myDoc, vbNormal`

Comment: hmmm. I still get the same debugger error

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: `FileCopy myDoc, ExportedFolder & "\" & strFile` highlighted                  The debugger error: RunTime error '462' The remote server machine does not exist or is unabailable

Comment: My mistake!!!!. Change the line to `FileCopy myFolder & "\" & strFile, ExportedFolder & "\" & strFile`, and also the *kill* line to `Kill myFolder & "\" & strFile`

Comment: Did the change and debugger error still picks up `FileCopy` line                        `myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
FileCopy myFolder & "\" & strFile, ExportedFolder & "\" & strFile
Kill myFolder & "\" & strFile
    
strFile = Dir()`

Comment: Have you created the folder `Interviews - Exported` under `Retention DB`?

Comment: Yes. I have 'Interviews' folder where the original word docs reside and 'Iinterviews - Exported' folder. However, with the changed line now                  `FileCopy myFolder & "\" & strFile, ExportedFolder & "\" & strFile`                      I get debugger error  70: permissions denied

Comment: It worked !!! I had to simply restart the excel doc with Macro. Tested and all works as your last solution. Many thanks !